# Read info of pdf file without reading whole file

Tags: .net, pdf, itext

I need to get the information of pdf file.

There is my code:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(fileName);
var info = reader.Info;
```

I don't need to read the whole file: if there are a lot of pdf files, this operation may take a lot of time..

How can I get info without reading whole file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's explained in [Chapter 6](http://www.manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf) of the [official documentation](http://itextpdf.com/book):

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new RandomAccessFileOrArray(file), null);
```

Comment: Unfortunately that constructor (I assume `file` is a `String`) has been marked "deprecated" (Java-style) and the use of the constructor accepting a `RandomAccessSource` is suggested.